# Graphviz Dot, mix directed and undirected

Tags: graph, graphviz, relation, symmetry

For my application I need to represent simultaneously (on the same graph) two relations: one is simmetric, the other is not.

Targets:

- Ideally the two relation should result in edges having different colors;
- For the symmetric relation I would like not to have double-edges;

Is there a way of doing this with *dot*?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
digraph {

    A; B; C

    subgraph Rel1 {
        edge [dir=none, color=red]
        A -> B -> C -> A
    }

    subgraph Rel2 {
        edge [color=blue]

        B -> C
        C -> A
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Does anybody know simpler solution of combining gigraph with graph?

Comment: @user1742529 Not sure what you mean, there’s no such combination happening here. Possibly you’re confused by the word “subgraph”; that’s just basic compartmentalization, a way of saying THESE lines should be blue and THOSE lines should be orange.

Comment: @Frungi, sorry. I mean: simpler solution for combining "digraph" with "graph"? ( https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#graphviz.Digraph )

Answer (score 16):

You can pass `dir=none` as an edge property to the undirected graph connections:

```
digraph {

    A; B; C
    
    A -> B
    B -> C
    C -> A [dir=none]
}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer helped me, for the case where you have only one relation, but conditional.