# Mixed directed/undirected graph

Tags: graphviz, dot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Graphviz Dot, mix directed and undirected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236975/graphviz-dot-mix-directed-and-undirected)

I need to draw a directed graph that has some undirected edges. Is this possible using GraphViz? Just using `--` in a `digraph` `->` in a `graph` is a syntax error.